# Direction derivatives help

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let
>   $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if } \ y = x^{2} \text{ and } (x,y)\ne (0,0);\\
> 0 & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}.$$
>   Find all directional derivatives $D_{u}f(0,0)$ for $u\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, $\lVert u\rVert = 1$.  Is $f$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

I really just don't understand how to begin this problem. How do I go about taking this derivative? Do I take the derivative of $y=x^2$ or of the $1$ and $0$? Or am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function $f$ is differentiable in the open set $\Omega = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y \ne x^2\}$. In this set you can use the use the usual rules for derivatives and get
$$
D_v f (x,y) = \nabla f \cdot v = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} v_1 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} v_2 = 0\cdot v_1 + 0 \cdot v_2= 0
$$

as for the other points, you need to use the definition of directional derivative. In particular for $(0,0)$ you have that

$$
D_v f(0,0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{f(0+t v_1, 0 + t v_2)-f(0,0)}{t} =  \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{0-0}{t} = 0
$$

At other points of the parabola $y=x^2$ the directional derivative does not exist.

Regarding differentiability at $(0,0)$, we need to analyse the limit
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{f(x,y)-0 \cdot x - 0 \cdot y -f(0,0)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$

Since this limit is not zero (the limit along the parabola is $\infty$), we conclude that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: The function $f\equiv 0$ in $\Omega.$ It's then obvious that $Df(x)=0$ for all $x\in \Omega.$ I'm not sure why your'e going through that computation. More importantly, you are not answering the question. The question asks about derivatives at $(0,0).$ For some reason you treat derivatives at all points $\ne (0,0).$ And you've made a mistake even there. There are no directional derivatives equal to $\infty$ anywhere.

Comment: I'll complete my answer to comply with the current form of the question.

Comment: @zhw the current form of the question is not the same as the original one (there was a link to a picture...). I computed the directional derivative  on $\Omega$ with that level of detail for pedagogical reasons, to show how it would play out if $f$ was not constant.